# partition table necessary for dd?

Tags: command-line

Here is installation of 12.10 without partition table.

Now I want to make a copy of harddisk 1:1 onto a bigger harddisk.

Is `dd if=/dev/harddisk1 of=/dev/harddisk2`
working ?

Or do I need to make a partition table first with fdisk resp. cfdisk ?

---

Thanks for the link.

Have I to care about block-size in reference to between normal hard-disk (silicium) and ssd-harddisk ? or is block-size not mattering whether if normal hard-disk resp. ssd ?

Answer (score 0):

dd will partition the disk for you according to http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-newbie-8/learn-the-dd-command-362506/.